# AsParallel () and Any()?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, plinq

I've seen this code which check a condition using `AsParallel()` and `Any()`  :

```
bool IsAnyDeviceConnected()
{
   return m_devices.Any(d => d.IsConnected);
}
```

and to make it faster :

```
bool IsAnyDeviceConnected()
{
   return m_devices.AsParallel().Any(d => d.IsConnected);
}
```

But looking at `Any()` :

```
 internal static bool Any<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate) {
            foreach (T element in source) {
                if (predicate(element)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
```

I don't see (*obviously*)  - that it does care about *cancellation  of other workers - once found*.

However - this (*other*) code does "finish - soon as possible" +  cancel other future work :

```
bool IsAnyDeviceConnected()
{
   var res = Parallel.ForEach(m_devices,
      (d,loopState) => {  
         if (d.IsConnected) 
            loopState.Stop();
      });
   return !res.IsCompleted;
}
```

**Question :**

Does my diagnostics correct?  Does `Any()` - once found item , doesn't cancel other threads ( in AsParallel context)

*nb , my fear is that I might looking at the wrong source code.*

Comment: You're looking at the wrong source. You need to look at [ParalellEnumerable.Any](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/ParallelEnumerable.cs) which is way complicated than what you see `Enumerable.Any`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[`AsParallel()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd413237(v=vs.100).aspx) returns a `ParallelQuery`, so if you call `AsParallel().Any(...)` you're not calling [`Enumerable.Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb337697(v=vs.100).aspx), but [`ParallelEnumerable.Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dd413349(v=vs.110).aspx).

The reference source code for `ParallelEnumerable.Any` is [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/ParallelEnumerable.cs).

When you dig e.g. into the [`AnyAllSearchOperatorEnumerator`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Parallel/QueryOperators/Unary/AnyAllSearchOperator.cs) class, you see that a flag called `resultFoundFlag` is used to [tell other workers that a result is found](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Parallel/QueryOperators/Unary/AnyAllSearchOperator.cs#220) so [they can stop searching](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Parallel/QueryOperators/Unary/AnyAllSearchOperator.cs#214).

Answer (score 7):

You're looking at the wrong code. [`AsParallel`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/ParallelEnumerable.cs) returns a `ParallelQuery<TSource>`, and `ParellelQuery` has another overload for [`Any`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/ParallelEnumerable.cs).

'Any' creates a new `AnyAllSearchOperator` object and aggregates it. If you dig deeper into that chain of method calls and objects you'll find that the `QueryOpeningEnumerator` does support cancellation.

---

Unfortunately the reference source links to those particular member functions are bugged.

Answer (score 5):

You are looking at the wrong code. `ParallelEnumerable.AsParallel` returns a `ParallelQuery<>`. ParallelEnumerable also defines its own [Any](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.parallelenumerable.any(v=vs.100).aspx) extension method.

In order to specify cancellation, degrees of parallelism etc you need to use ParallelEnumerable's WithXXX extension methods like [WithCancellation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd413259(v=vs.100).aspx) and [WithDegreeOfParallelism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383719(v=vs.100).aspx). ParallelEnumerable.Any doesn't allow you to specify those options to preserve a similar signature as `Enumerable.Any`