# VB.Net Async - Check large list of string for a match

Tags: vb.net, asynchronous, async-await

I need this function to run Async, but can't seem to figure a way to do it.

LIST1 is Public and contains a List(of String) with a few hundred entries. List Declaration:

```
Public LIST1 As New List(Of String)
```

Normally, I'd run the following code to retrieve the boolean of whether or not he list contains the entry:

```
Dim result = LIST1.Any(Function(s) value.ToLower.Contains(s))
```

Full non-Async function:

```
Function CheckValue(byval value As String) As Boolean
    Dim result As Boolean = LIST1.Any(Function(s) value.ToLower.Contains(s))
    Return result
End Function
```

That works well as expected.

How would I implement the same as an Async function? I've tried:

```
Async Function CheckValue(byval value as String) As Task(Of Boolean)
    Dim result as Task(Of Boolean) = Await LIST1.Any(Function(s) value.ToLower.Contains(s))
    Return result
End Function
```

I get the following error: 'Await' requires that the type 'Boolean' have a suitable GetAwaiter method.

Any thoughts?

Comment: `Any()` is not async. You cannot make it to be async. It does not make sense to create an async wrapper for it either because it's not IO-bound.

Comment: You want to [use `Task.Run`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28071880/11683) or [`AsParallel.Any`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25379025/11683).

Comment: Consider eliminating superfluous string allocations.  Instead of  `value.ToLower.Contains(s)` (`ToLower` creates a new string), use `value.IndexOf(s, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) > 0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not return a task, so there is no reason to await it.  If your concern is that it is too slow, you can run any synchronous code in a new thread, and then await the completion of that thread, like this:

```
Dim result As Boolean = Await Task.Run(Function() LIST1.Any(Function(s) value.ToLower.Contains(s)))
```

Or, as GSerg mentioned, though it technically doesn't make it awaitable, you can use `AsParallel.Any`:

```
Dim result As Boolean = LIST1.AsParallel.Any(Function(s) value.ToLower.Contains(s))
```

However, be aware that starting new threads has a fair amount of overhead, so starting up a new thread, just to do a small amount of work, may make it actually run slower.

In this particular case, if performance is key, I would recommend looking into various search/indexing algorithms.  For instance, take a look at some of the ones mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3183582/what-is-the-fastest-substring-search-algorithm).  I wouldn't be surprised if there are opensource .NET libraries for those kinds of algorithms.

Comment: Thanks @Steven Doggart , that explanation helps. I appreciate it.